# Processing data by multiple threads simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

We have an application that regularly receives multimedia messages, and should reply to them.

We currently do this with a single thread, first receiving messages, and then processing them one by one. This does the job, but is slow.

So we're now thinking of doing the same process but with multiple threads sumultaneously.

Any simple way to allow parallel processing of the incoming records, yet avoid erroneously processing the same record by two threads?

Comment: simple and elegant -> will raise discussion ...

Comment: How are you receiving the records? If with TCP/IP you could have one listening thread, which will create one thread for each incoming record.

Comment: It's hard to give a specific answer. Things you can look at range from the Parallel.For method in .NET to Azure service bus with multiple scalable worker roles. If you can specify more information and even some sample code we should be able to offer more specific advice.

Comment: How are records coming? Place some code so maybe we can help you to make it multithreaded.

Comment: How about still receiving them on a single thread, and then have that thread kick off new threads for the processing? Unless the receiving takes alot of time too, of course.

Comment: You can make two threads. One for receiving messages and storing them in a collection and then passing them to a second thread when a certain count has reached where they will be processed.

Answer (score 1):

> Any simple way to allow parallel processing of the incoming records, yet avoid erroneously processing the same record by two threads?

Yes it is actually not too hard, what you are wanting to do is called the "Producer-Consumer model"

If your message receiver could only handle one thread at a time but your message "processor" can work on multiple messages at once you just need to use a [BlockingCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) to store the work that needs to be processed

```
public sealed class MessageProcessor : IDisposable
{
    public MessageProcessor() 
        : this(-1)
    {   
    }

    public MessageProcessor(int maxThreadsForProcessing)
    {
        _maxThreadsForProcessing = maxThreadsForProcessing;
        _messages = new BlockingCollection<Message>();
        _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

        _messageProcessorThread = new Thread(ProcessMessages);
        _messageProcessorThread.IsBackground = true;
        _messageProcessorThread.Name = "Message Processor Thread";
        _messageProcessorThread.Start();
    }

    public int MaxThreadsForProcessing
    {
        get { return _maxThreadsForProcessing; }
    }

    private readonly BlockingCollection<Message> _messages;
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts;
    private readonly Thread _messageProcessorThread;
    private bool _disposed = false;
    private readonly int _maxThreadsForProcessing;


    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new message to be queued up and processed in the background.
    /// </summary>
    public void ReceiveMessage(Message message)
    {
       _messages.Add(message);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Signals the system to stop processing messages.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="finishQueue">Should the queue of messages waiting to be processed be allowed to finish</param>
    public void Stop(bool finishQueue)
    {
        _messages.CompleteAdding();
        if(!finishQueue)
            _cts.Cancel();

        //Wait for the message processor thread to finish it's work.
        _messageProcessorThread.Join();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// The background thread that processes messages in the system
    /// </summary>
    private void ProcessMessages()
    {
        try
        {
            Parallel.ForEach(_messages.GetConsumingEnumerable(),
                         new ParallelOptions()
                         {
                             CancellationToken = _cts.Token,
                             MaxDegreeOfParallelism = MaxThreadsForProcessing
                         },
                         ProcessMessage);
        }
        catch (OperationCanceledException)
        {
            //Don't care that it happened, just don't want it to bubble up as a unhandeled exception.
        }
    }

    private void ProcessMessage(Message message, ParallelLoopState loopState)
    {
        //Here be dragons! (or your code to process a message, your choice :-))

        //Use if(_cts.Token.IsCancellationRequested || loopState.ShouldExitCurrentIteration) to test if 
        // we should quit out of the function early for a graceful shutdown.
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if(!_disposed)
        {
            if(_cts != null && _messages != null && _messageProcessorThread != null)
                Stop(true); //This line will block till all queued messages have been processed, if you want it to be quicker you need to call `Stop(false)` before you dispose the object.

            if(_cts != null)
                _cts.Dispose();

            if(_messages != null)
                _messages.Dispose();

            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
           _disposed = true;
        }
    }

    ~MessageProcessor()
    {
        //Nothing to do, just making FXCop happy.
    }

}
```

I highly recommend you read the free book [Patterns for Parallel Programming](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222), it goes in to some detail about this. There is a entire section explaining the Producer-Consumer model in detail.

---

**UPDATE:** There are some performance issues with `GetConsumingEnumerable()` and `Parallel.ForEach(`, instead use the library [`ParallelExtensionsExtras`](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/ParExtSamples) and it's new extension method [`GetConsumingPartitioner()`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx)

```
public static Partitioner<T> GetConsumingPartitioner<T>(
    this BlockingCollection<T> collection)
{
    return new BlockingCollectionPartitioner<T>(collection);
}

private class BlockingCollectionPartitioner<T> : Partitioner<T>
{
    private BlockingCollection<T> _collection;

    internal BlockingCollectionPartitioner(
        BlockingCollection<T> collection)
    {
        if (collection == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
        _collection = collection;
    }

    public override bool SupportsDynamicPartitions {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public override IList<IEnumerator<T>> GetPartitions(
        int partitionCount)
    {
        if (partitionCount < 1)
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("partitionCount");
        var dynamicPartitioner = GetDynamicPartitions();
        return Enumerable.Range(0, partitionCount).Select(_ =>
            dynamicPartitioner.GetEnumerator()).ToArray();
    }

    public override IEnumerable<T> GetDynamicPartitions()
    {
        return _collection.GetConsumingEnumerable();
    }
}
```